# Uncaught Type: Undefined is not a function JS error

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I have been looking for this and tried with lot of found solutions but that didn't work in my case.
In my MVC 4 application with dropdown change event I am calling a JS method to pass the selected value to the controller which works fine but in console I've been getting this error continuoulsy in every change event.

Following is my razor source for dropdown:

```
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustId) 
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustId, new SelectList(Model.ddlCust, "Value", "Text"), "All Customer", new { id = "CustID", onchange = "ShowCust()", @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustId)
   </div>
```

And my **JS** client function looks like:

```
<script>
    function ShowCust() {
            var custId = $("#CustID").val();
            var Url = "@Url.Content("~/Customer/GetCustId")";
            $.ajax({
                url: Url,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { CustID: custId },
                success: function (data) {
                    return data;
                }
            });
        }
</script>
```

In Console it throws the error on every dropdown change:

```
uncaught type error: undefined is not a function.
```

And finally in source it shows as:

```
<script>(function() {with (this[2]) {with (this[1]) {with (this[0]) {return function(event) {ShowCust()
};}}}})</script>
```

Also it marks the part with underline in braces before function ShowCust (`{`ShowCust).

I am not able to figure out what exactly I am doing mistake over here.

Does anyone see any issues with my html or javascript? Or the way I written the script? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you included file with `ShowCust` function, into the HTML page itself?

Comment: @JibiAbraham Yes, it is in the same razor view.

Comment: on which line does the error occur?

Comment: @Dropout, In console, it says on Line2, Column 1 showing the part
{ ShowCust() } and marks the curly braces with underscores.

Comment: I thought I saw a problem, but I was wrong.. This is wierd.. Do you use jQuery before this line without problems? Can you pastebin the whole file? It might help..

Comment: @Dropout , I just updated my script part in question and that is all what I have been using . I guess you were asking the complete same part.Please let me know if you want more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
I think you have miss out the '@' for Id & onChange
```

new { @id = "CustID", @onchange = "ShowCust()", @class = "form-control" })

@id = "CustID"
@onchange = "ShowCust()"